# Mavenizing legacy projects with custom packaging type

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I have some legacy eclipse projects that should not be changed and some newer projects that could be ported to maven projects.

I would like to port these newer projects now to maven projects, but they depend on some legacy projects. My problem now is, that I need to add the output folders of the dependent projects to the compile classpath.

I thought of creating a plugin or so, that will handle all that, but I am not sure how I can alter the classpaths.

Can anyone help me with a basic plugin structure for accomplishing this task, or is the altering of classpaths not possible in that way?

Answer (score 2):

You should build the old projects and add them as `jar` files to your Maven repository. You can then mark them as dependencies to your Maven projects.

Comment: I know that but I want to alter the classpath if possible. The other projects(IBM EJB 1.1) are still developed. I should not change anything in these projects. Unfortunately there are also some hard to resolve circular dependencies in the old projects so I can't mavenize these.

Comment: @ChristianBeikov You don't need to mavenize the old ones. Just build them and use maven only to deploy the jars of them.